# Failure to fsck a still-working filesystem

Tags: debian, lvm, ext4, fsck

I'm currently working with a large ext4 filesystem (15TB) on an LVM volume spanning multiple disks. Because the filesystem was nearly full, I added more disks to the volume group and extended the LV to 25TB.

After doing this, I attempted to resize the filesystem to fill the disk. However, it failed and I got:

```
root@gnubee:~# resize2fs /dev/mapper/data-data 
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
resize2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/mapper/data-data
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

After this, I tried running `e2fsck` over the filesystem, but ran into the same error:

```
root@gnubee:~# e2fsck -v /dev/mapper/data-data 
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/mapper/data-data
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

The strange thing is, the filesystem still works perfectly well for mount and unmount, the data in the filesystem is visible, and there don't seem to be any errors in dmesg or journal output. I've searched for that error message, but it only ever seems to come up online in a context where the filesystem is damaged and refuses to mount.

What's going on here? How can I get this filesystem fully functional again?